# Hibernate doesn't use setter when field is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, setter

I want to validate data before saving it to a DB (check if field is not null, add matches to the regex in setter). But if the field is null, Hibernate doesn't use the setter. What should I do in this case?

```
@Column(name = "table_name")
private String tableName;

public void setTableName(String tableName) {
    Assert.hasText(tableName); // Assert.hasText() - method from Spring util
    this.tableName = tableName;
}
```

So I want the method `Assert.hasText()` to throw an exception if tableName is null.

Comment: You have put annotations on the fields, which means hibernate is using field access and not property access. If you require a field to be required just use the hibernate validator and put `@NotNull` on the field. Use proper validation.

Comment: bean validation is nothing to do with the JPA API. It is the Bean Validation API, as pointed out above. There is nothing in the JPA spec to force an implementation to use a setter (which may have other inappropriate code in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at hibernate docs. With hibernate annotations you can validate a lot of cool things like: Null fields, field size, etc ...

Here's the doc:

http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

It's very friendly ;)

Comment: FWIW That is the Bean Validation API, and here's a more vendor neutral URL http://beanvalidation.org/

Comment: Ok, thank you. In this case (if field is null) I've had few exceptions, how should I handle this exceptions: ConstraintViolationException, RollbackException, TransactionSystemException?